# How could a local file be loaded in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I tried to load a local file in my javascript file by using Fetch API having no result.

*"It couldn't be loaded as URL scheme "file" is not supported".*

So i decided to try using XMLHttpRequest API but nothing changed, as i got CORS error.

"*from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https*".

how can it be done?

Comment: Because you can't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me clear some facts:

1. To load any file through a http protocol, you need to create a server
   that is able to fetch the file from the filesystem for you.

Let's say you have a file.txt file lying around, and you want to load it, so you can definietly do it but you need to setup a server such that it can capture the query you want.

Now, I recommend using POST request in this case, and fs library with express in backend.